# Javas GregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime() returns different date for dates in the past

Tags: java, datetime, zoneddatetime

For some date in the past, GregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime() returns a date that is 1 day off.

For 2nd April 1893, toZonedDateTime() returns the same date, for 1st April 1893, ZonedDateTime shows me the 31st March 1893 and there is also a difference in the "day of the year" values. There is always an offset for dates before this "magic" date.

Here is some sample code:

```
final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(1893, 0, 1); // Set to 1st January 1893
for(int i = 1; i < 365; i++) {
    gc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i); // Update day of year
    final ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime();

    System.out.println(String.format(
            "GC: %02d.%02d.%d (%d) -> ZDT: %02d.%02d.%d (%d)", 
            gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, // "+1" is needed, because GregorianCalendar encodes January as 0.
            gc.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR),
            zdt.getDayOfMonth(),
            zdt.getMonthValue(),
            zdt.getYear(),
            zdt.getDayOfYear()
            ));
}
```

When running the code, you will get the output

```
[...]
GC: 31.03.1893 (90) -> ZDT: 30.03.1893 (89)
GC: 01.04.1893 (91) -> ZDT: 31.03.1893 (90)
GC: 02.04.1893 (92) -> ZDT: 02.04.1893 (92)
GC: 03.04.1893 (93) -> ZDT: 03.04.1893 (93)
[...]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Best regards,
Markus

Comment: FWIW in Europ/Berlin time zone I get the same result as you. When I run your code in Europe/Copenhagen time zone, I get discrepancies the whole year, from `GC: 01.01.1893 (1) -> ZDT: 31.12.1892 (366)` up to `GC: 30.12.1893 (364) -> ZDT: 29.12.1893 (363)`.

Answer (score 4):

What is your system timezone?

I suspect you may be in a locale which observes, or observed, a DST type change on the 1st April 1893. Try printing out the `offset` value of the `ZonedDateTime` at each iteration of your loop.

Or a little more info can be gleaned by removing the timezone factor `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(zdt.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC)`

---

Seems this is related to Berlin choosing to adopt CET on that date

> ## The tzdata file europe contains only one zone Europe/Berlin for all of Germany.
>
> ## It is not the best possible choice for several reasons:
>
> ## - Berlin started CET only in 1893, later than several southern states.

https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2011-August/008736.html

Comment: Timezone is always "Europe/Berlin", but for the date the zone offset changes from "+00:53:28" (1st April) to "+01:00" (2nd April)…

Comment: Seems like that's a DST type change https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/germany/berlin?year=1893

Comment: Thank you, ptomli. That's it.

When settings time from midnight to noon, the dates are correct. Damn DST...

Comment: As noted, it's not actually a DST change, but rather the date that Berlin decided to adopt CET. Date/time history is a fascinating if treacherous subject ;-)

Comment: Just a reminder to accept the answer if it's correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaDocs of `GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime--):

> `public ZonedDateTime toZonedDateTime()`
>
> Converts this object to a ZonedDateTime that represents the same point on the time-line as this GregorianCalendar.
>
> Since this object supports a Julian-Gregorian cutover date and ZonedDateTime does not, **it is possible that the resulting year, month and day will have different values**. The result will represent the correct date in the ISO calendar system, which will also be the same value for Modified Julian Days.

I think it is some kind of non-desired but expected behaviour.

Comment: I think that comment is intended to allow for differences in as a result of the Julian Gregorian cut-over, around 15 Oct 1582

Comment: @ptomli Possible, I may delete this answer as soon as I find out its wrong ;-)

Comment: Don't delete it, it does add value

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it’s a bug in `GregorianCalendar`. I have before seen bugs in `Date` for dates before 1900 in certain time zones. I consider `ZonedDateTime` and the other classes from java.time solider and more trustworthy.

Berlin was at offset +0:53:28 until April 1, 1893 00:00. At day of year 89 (for the sake of an example) your code gives a `ZonedDateTime` of 1893-03-29T23:53:28+00:53:28[Europe/Berlin] giving the correct offset. But both your `GregorianCalendar` and your `ZonedDateTime` represent a moment of 1893-03-29T23:00:00Z (UTC), so the `GregorianCalendar` seems to have assumed an offset of +01:00 instead, which is wrong. The conversion converts the moment correctly (and also the time zone correctly) and therefore the individual date and time fields incorrectly.

**Source:** For the offset for Berlin up until 1893 go to [Time Zone in Berlin, Germany](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin) on timeanddate.com. Under “Time Changes in Berlin Over the Years”, in the dropdown on the top right select “1850 — 1899”. For the years 1850–92 you will see “No changes, UTC +0:53:28 hours all of the period”, and a change on April 1, 1893 at 00:00 to CET/UTC +1.

Here’s what I tried within your loop:

```
    System.out.println(gc.getTimeZone().getID());
    System.out.println(gc.getTime());
    System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(gc.getTimeInMillis()));
    System.out.println();

    final ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime();

    System.out.println(zdt);
    System.out.println(zdt.toInstant());
```

Output for day of year (`i`) 89 was:

> ```
> Europe/Berlin
> Thu Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 1893
> 1893-03-29T23:00:00Z
>
> 1893-03-29T23:53:28+00:53:28[Europe/Berlin]
> 1893-03-29T23:00:00Z
> ```